Redeclaring a variable causes calculation errors
I was looking for calculation errors in an old C++ Win32 program compiled by VS Pro 2022.
The problem was found to be caused by the following code which always produced a result of zero:
double dMetalFrameR = 0.0;
if (m_dMetalDoorK)
    double dMetalFrameR = m_dMetalDoorX / m_dMetalDoorK;

Once the redeclaration was removed, it worked correctly:
double dMetalFrameR = 0.0;
if (m_dMetalDoorK)
    dMetalFrameR = m_dMetalDoorX / m_dMetalDoorK;

The redeclaration is obviously incorrect, but why is the result always zero?
I would have expected a compiler warning but correct calculation.

If you redeclare it within the 'if' scope then you will have two variables with the same name. The second one will only live - and die - within the scope of the 'if' (so, not very long!). Then you will be left with the original. Which is 0.0.

"Result of zero" - where does the result come from? From reading dMetalFrameR? Well, you have two of them in the first case.

"I would have expected a compiler warning" there is.

MSVC also gives warnings (both about variable name hiding and about unreferenced variable), but only at warning level 4 (i.e. /W4).

You're not redeclaring a variable, you're declaring a new, distinct, variable with the same name.

The technical term for this is "shadowing", not redeclaring. extern double dMetalFrameR; double dMetaFrameR = 0.0; in the same scope would instead be redeclaring.

Hint: The program would compile to the same binary code if you changed the name of the variable in if.

Assuming there is a return dMetalFrameR; at the end of that function, then the result is always 0.0 because that variable is never changed from its initial value.
This, incorrect, code:
double dMetalFrameR = 0.0;
if (m_dMetalDoorK)
    double dMetalFrameR = m_dMetalDoorX / m_dMetalDoorK;

Creates a new variable with the same name and then discards it when the if statement goes out-of-scope.
